# Simplicity of high-order groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order
$$|G|=\prod^n_{i=1}p_i$$
where each $p_i$ is a prime number and
$$n\geq2\qquad \text{and} \qquad k\neq j\implies p_k\neq p_j \qquad \text{and} \qquad p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_n$$
I want to prove that $G$ is non-simple. I have tried to use Sylow's Theorem, some direct product tools but nothing. Is there some other theorem or method that can help me to prove it?

Comment: I take it you meant to exclude the case where $n=1$?  It is the case that all groups of square free order are solvable, See, e.g., [this](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/bachelor/2016-2017/achterhof.pdf)

Comment: This group is a semi-direct product of cyclic groups (this might help) You could try with the dihedral group first (with $p>2$ prime)?

Comment: Every finite group with an order not divisible by $4$ is solvable , in particular not simple.

Comment: @lulu thanks, I forgot the case n=1, I fix that

Comment: @user10354138 thanks, I will read it, it's looks like very intersting

Comment: @Peter why? I didn't find de proof of that

Comment: The condition $p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_n$ makes redundant $k\neq j\implies p_k\neq p_j$.

Comment: @citadel Hi, I now that, but I wrote that when I was trying to solve it using the Sylow Theorems, because you use that for element count

Answer (score 0):

This theorem is what you need:

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$. If a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ has a normal $p$-complement.

It follows immediately from this theorem that a finite group of square-free order cannot be simple, since all of its Sylow subgroups are cyclic.

A normal $p$-complement is a normal subgroup $N\triangleleft G$ such that  $p$ does not divide $|N|$ and $|G:N|$ is a power of $p$. For example, if a group $G$ has order $60=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5$, then a normal $2$-complement of $G$ would have $15=3\cdot 5$ elements.

The theorem I cited above is not easy to prove. The only proof I know uses Burnside's normal $p$-complement theorem, which is usually proven using transfer theory or character theory.